# How to 'get data from nested array structure in PHP'

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get data from array including `DetectedText` values and `BoundingBox` all four values. but facing issue.

The complete data is in '$prepared_arr' and structure of given array is given below.

```
print_r ($prepared_arr);// variable having complete data
Array //output of above array used in pipeline
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DetectedText] => The number of goals
        [BoundingBox] => Array
            (
                [Width] => 0.66954100131989
                [Top] => 0.04796177148819
                [Left] => 0.2710283100605
                [Height] => 0.072451308369637
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DetectedText] => in world cup match
        [BoundingBox] => Array
            (
                [Width] => 0.33683118224144
                [Top] => 0.12350185215473
                [Left] => 0.12564577162266
                [Height] => 0.066131837666035
            )

    )
)
```

if I use print_r ($prepared_arr[1]) it only return index 1 complete data.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What __issue__ are you facing?

Comment: *if I use print_r ($prepared_arr[1]) it only return index 1 complete data.* whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to get data from an array something like:

```
// with your example
foreach($prepared_arr as $val)
{
    echo "DetectedText: ". $val['DetectedText']."<br/>"; // using br for line break
    foreach ($val['BoundingBox'] as $key => $valueInner) {
        echo $key.": ".$valueInner."<br/>"; // using br for line break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following loops

**[FOR LOOP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)**

**Syntax :-**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 echo $i;
}
```

**[FOREACH](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**

**Syntax :-**

```
$a = [1,2,3]
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you execute the code `print_r($prepared_arr[1])` it fetchs only 1th of the array $prepared_arr ignoring 0-index, thus it is printing complete data of 1-index. 
I suggest you go through https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-an-array-in-php/ to understand how php arrays are accessed